# Angular2 ContentChild with multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is this possible to set multiple selectors in ContentChild?

For example, I'm looking for a solution similar to it:

```
@ContentChild(Case1 | Case2)
```

To be able to get Case2 values if Case1 aren't available.

Without this solution I must create two seperate ContentChild's.

```
@ContentChild(Case1)
@ContentChild(Case2)
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18280

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ContentChildren with multiple content types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278479/contentchildren-with-multiple-content-types)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can simply use `@ContentChildren` which is some kind of array. Here take a look at [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren). It has `QueryList` type which can be easly converted to array by using `map` or `toArray` function, and then all you need to do is what element is exists, also you can subscribe for it's changes via `changes` property which is `Observable`.

Comment: I'm not writing about ContentChildren. I'm writing about searching by multiple selectors