# ContentChildren with multiple content types

Tags: angular

Hello I am currently building a table that will allow multiple column types in it. I want to be able to use this like:

```html
<my-table [rows]="rows">
     <text-column [someParameters]="here" header="text"></text-column>
     <icon-column [someParameters]="here" header="icon"></icon-column>
</my-table>
```

`text-column` and `icon-column` are separate directives.

I currently have an abstract class called `column` and lets say the `text-column` and the `icon-column` may look something like:

```ts
   export abstract class Column
   {
       @Input() someParameters:string;
       @Input() header:string;
   }

   export class TextColumnDirective extends Column
   {
      //I do cool stuff here
   }

   export class IconColumnDirective extends Column
   {
      //I do different cool stuff   
   }
```

My table may look something like:

```ts
@Component({
   selector:'my-table',
   template: `
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column.header}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
   `
})
export class MyTableComponent
{
    @ContentChildren(Column) columns:QueryList<any>;

    //I do cool stuff too
}
```

So this approach works if I do not use an abstract and just call it with just text column like `@ContentChildren(TextColumnDirective) columns:QueryList<any>;`
but only gets the text column and the same with the icon column. How can I accomplish this where I can add different types of directives for different columnTypes later?

Comment: You should look at this Github comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8580#issuecomment-218331920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in the comments above I was told to look at comment at a link they provided.

That said, they we're correct in the answer I will post the code here for the next person.

```html
<my-table [rows]="rows">
  <text-column [someParameters]="here" header="text"></text-column>
  <icon-column [someParameters]="here" header="icon"></icon-column>
</my-table>
```

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'text-column',
  provider: [{provide:Column,useExisting:forwardRef(() => TextColumnDirective)})
})
export class TextColumnDirective extends Column
{
  // ...
}

@Directive({
  selector: 'icon-column',
  provider:[{provide:Column, useExisting:forwardRef(() => IconColumnDirective)})
})
export class IconColumnDirective extends Column
{
  // ...
}
```

Hope this helps next person.

Comment: Is `forwardRef` needed here? It's not used in this example https://netbasal.com/angular-components-tips-and-tricks-d9e725871d58 (tip #2).

Answer (score 11):

The answer from @3xGuy is correct but the `forwardRef(() => {})` is not required unless the type being provided is defined after the decorator or the decorated class [see this Angular In Depth post](https://indepth.dev/what-is-forwardref-in-angular-and-why-we-need-it/)

Note this approach can be used for `ContentChildren` or `ViewChildren`, below I use `ViewChildren`

**item.ts**

```js
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

export class Item {
  color = '';
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[blueItem]',
  providers: [{ provide: Item, useExisting: BlueItemDirective }],
})
export class BlueItemDirective { // 'extends Item' is optional
  color = 'blue';
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[redItem]',
  providers: [{ provide: Item, useExisting: RedItemDirective }],
})
export class RedItemDirective { // 'extends Item' is optional
  color = 'red';
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

import { Item } from './item';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Multiple View Child Types';

  // Note we query for 'Item' here and not `RedItemDirective'
  // or 'BlueItemDirective' but this query selects both types
  @ViewChildren(Item) viewItems: QueryList<Item>;

  itemColors: string[] = [];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.itemColors = this.viewItems.map(item => item.color);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div redItem>Item</div>
<div blueItem>Item</div>
<div blueItem>Item</div>
<div blueItem>Item</div>
<div redItem>Item</div>

<h2>Colors of the above directives</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let color of itemColors">{{color}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiple-view-child-types) showing this behavior in action.