# different type of ContentChildren

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component (radio-group) that group some other component (radio-button)

To get all the button contained in the group I do this :

```js
  @ContentChildren(RadioButtonComponent, { descendants: true })
  radios: QueryList<RadioButtonComponent>;
```

with radioButton being a normal angular component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-radio-button',
  templateUrl: './radio-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radio-button.component.scss'],
})
export class RadioButtonComponent implements Radio {
  @Input() value: any;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  // etc...
}
```

now, I want to create a new type of radio button with a different template, but the same code as radioButton for ex

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-radio-tiled-button',
  templateUrl: './radio-tiled-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radio-tiled-button.component.scss'],
})
export class RadioTiledButtonComponent implements Radio {
  @Input() value: any;
  @Input() image: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  // etc...
}
```

The problem is, although they share the same public method and interface, I do not find a way to recover all of them inside the ContentChildren

```js
  @ContentChildren(RadioButtonComponent, { descendants: true })
  radios: QueryList<RadioButtonComponent>;
```

how can I do that ?

I have seen this post => [ContentChildren with multiple content types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278479/contentchildren-with-multiple-content-types)

but it doesn't ANSWER my question because directive do not have template, so it's a different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they share the same public method and interfaces, you can always do a contentchildren using an abstract class.

In both of your components metadata, do the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ComponentA',
  provider: [{ provide: IParentComponent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => ComponentA) }],
  template: '',
})
export class ComponentA implements IParentComponent { 
  getSelectedValue(): { return 1; }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ComponentB',
  provider: [{ provide: IParentComponent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => ComponentB) }],
  template: '',
})
export class ComponentB implements IParentComponent { 
  getSelectedValue(): { return 1; }
}

// some example methods
export abstract class IParentComponent {
   abstract getSelectedValue(): number;
}
```

Followed by:
@ContentChildren(IParentComponent , { descendants: true })
radios: QueryList;

This will give you a handle to both of your components.

Comment: IParentComponent must be a component right ? not just an interface ?

Comment: IParent is an abstract class, it does not need to be a component. In the class, you can add definition for the shared methods. Check the updated code.

Comment: in the provider, and in content children it say `'IParentComponent' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: The error should be gone with abstract class